# Cannot render Rails partial inside a Script tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to execute this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <%= render( :partial => "shared/editor_link_js", locals: { editor: @editor }) %>
</script>
```

However this throws an error telling me that the partial `editor_link_js` is missing.

But if i run this alone:

```
<%= render( :partial => "shared/editor_link_js", locals: { editor: @editor }) %>
```

I find the partial. Does any one know what causes this and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

you have to do something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#div").html('#{escape_javascript(render(:partial => "shared/editor_link_js", locals: { editor: @editor })}');
</script>
```